# Generalization of phase based systems for card and board games

Tags: design-patterns, reinventing-the-wheel, entity-component-system

In an exercise of futility I'm trying to abstract and generalize a framework where to build any turn/rule based system. I've had a head start but after decompiling HearthStone I'm second-guessing that it may have higher complexity than I expected, at least for abstraction. So, I would like a peer review of the approach I am taking.

For the premises:

- No UI or IO bindings to maintain decoupling and testability. You
  should be able to unitest a full game.
- Entity-Component-System, better memory packing, data-oriented,
  deterministic.
- Centralized pushdown automaton for state control.

At the heart of the architecture is the interface/trait `IPhaseSystem`. It has a single method, `pushSystem()`, which returns an `array` of `IPhaseSystems`.

From that interface plus an entity processing system we compose an abstract `AbsGameSystem` class, which requires a `process()` method. ECS systems already give the possibility to override pre and post methods, but is not mandatory.

There is an interface `IVictory` with a single `isVictory()` method.

Initialization of the world requires a single `AbsGameSystem` and an `IVictory`.

My game world in every event-driven step processes the system atop of the pushdown automaton, and then proceeds to push all states returned by `pushSystem()`.

In my mind, from this simple setup and a communication pattern for UI/IO calls, like an Event Bus would be, should suffice to express any kind of board game akin to Catan, Magic: The Gathering, Dominion or Stratego.

Comment: While I can't remember the specifics of the abstraction, there was a bit about it (at a high, non-tech level, but one that could point you in the right direction) in [The Nudist on the Late Shift](http://www.amazon.com/The-Nudist-Late-Shift-Silicon/dp/0375502777).  The implementation was that of Yahoo Games.  Though *any* turn/rule based game could be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve top-down. Make it work for one game, then extend it to another, and another, until it's pretty general. If you make it work for at least two, it's hardly futile.